# How to assign a tuple type to rest params in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

Given a Function Type:

```
interface Fun {
  (a: string, b: number): void
}
```

And the following scenario where there is an extra param:

```
const foo = (ctx: any, a: string, b: number) => {}
```

it becomes simple to pass along the rest of the params as `RestParameters` instead of typing them all again.

For example, take a function that implements `Fun` and calls `foo` which takes similar params:

The following works:

```
const bar: Fun = (a, b) => {
  foo("calling from bar", a, b);
}
```

But when using rest parameters and spreading the params that are redundant, the type information gets lost:

```
const bar2: Fun = (...params) => {
  // error here params is of type any[]
  foo("calling from bar2", ...params);
}
```

At least, this should have worked:

```
const bar3: Fun => (...params) => {
  if (
    params.length > 1 
    && typeof params[0] === "string" 
    && typeof params[1] === "number"
  ) {
    foo("calling from bar3", ...params);
  }
}
```

[Try it in TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Fun%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20(a%3A%20string%2C%20b%3A%20number)%3A%20void%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20foo%20%3D%20(ctx%3A%20any%2C%20a%3A%20string%2C%20b%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20bar%3A%20Fun%20%3D%20(a%2C%20b)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20foo(%22calling%20from%20bar%22%2C%20a%2C%20b)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20bar2%3A%20Fun%20%3D%20(...params)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20error%20here%20params%20is%20of%20type%20any%5B%5D%0D%0A%20%20foo(%22calling%20from%20bar2%22%2C%20...params)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20bar3%3A%20Fun%20%3D%3E%20(...params)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20if%20(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20params.length%20%3E%201%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%26%26%20typeof%20params%5B0%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22string%22%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%26%26%20typeof%20params%5B1%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22number%22%0D%0A%20%20)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo(%22calling%20from%20bar3%22%2C%20...params)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

Is it possible to get a Tuple Type `[string, number]` for rest params in TypeScript? If so, how? and if not, am I missing something?

Comment: It's an [open issue in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4130).

Comment: No way, a lot of issue with this problem, and a lot of proposals: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453

Comment: As workaround just use object argument